# Different definitions for work in physics and thermodynamics

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, gas

In physics, work is defined as the force applied on an object multiplied by the distance traveled by that object. However, in thermodynamics, work is defined as a function of the opposing force. For example, if a gas expands inside a cylinder with a piston, work is defined as the opposing force (exerted as atmospheric pressure for example) times the displacement of the piston. Why is it not defined as a function of the pressure exerted by the gas? The gas exerts pressure on the piston and the piston moves. As defined in physics, the work would be defined as a function of the gas pressure. Is this some kind of misconception?

Comment: Is the force exerted by the gas on the piston equal in magnitude to the force exerted by the piston on the gas?

Comment: Note thermodynamics is *also* a sub-discipline of physics, so physics is internally inconsistent according to this question.